# Парсинг строки из json для html

Tags: html, python, json, парсер

Из `JSON` извлекается список данных такого формата:

```
('p.my-class#my-id', 'hello')
```

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы парсить ключ на `tag`, `id` и список `classes`.

На выходе должно получиться следующее:

```
'<p id="my-id" class="my-class">hello</p>'
```

Есть такое неудачное решение:

```
def getTagClassesId(s): # не учтено что ID может идти до или между классами
    """получение тега, класса и айди из элемента словаря"""
    _tag, _class, _id = None, None, None
    n_class, n_id = s.count('.'), s.count('#')
    if n_id > 0:
        s, _id = s.split('#')
    if n_class > 0:
        s = s.split('.')
        _class = s[1:]
        s = s[0]
    _tag = s
    return _tag, " ".join(_class), _id
```

Возможно есть готовая пакетная функция которая позволит избавиться от нужды в написании своей ф-ии парсинга ??

Comment: Что-то сомневаюсь что конвертировани css-selector'а в соответствующий tag может быть из коробки :) придется вручную писать алгоритм

Comment: а выражения id и class всегда присутствуют?

Comment: @alex-nasov , нет, `id` и/или `class` могут отсутствовать. `class` может быть больше одного и порядок у `class` и `id` может быть разный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация через регулярные выражения:

```json
import re


def get_tag_classes_id(text: str) -> (str, str, str):
    class_ = []
    id_ = ''

    tag, *items = re.split('[#.]', text)
    prefixs = re.findall('[#.]', text)

    for prefix, value in zip(prefixs, items):
        if prefix == '#':
            id_ = value
        else:
            class_.append(value)

    return tag, ' '.join(class_), id_


print(get_tag_classes_id('p.my-class.my-class2#my-id'))
print(get_tag_classes_id('p.my-class'))
print(get_tag_classes_id('p#my-id'))
print(get_tag_classes_id('p'))
```

Консоль:

```
('p', 'my-class my-class2', 'my-id')
('p', 'my-class', '')
('p', '', 'my-id')
('p', '', '')
```

---

**PS.** первоначально делал через другой алгоритм с регулярками, но мне он показался громоздким:

```json
def get_tag_classes_id(text: str) -> (str, str, str):
    match = re.search('(.+?)[.#]', text)
    if not match:
        return text, '', ''

    tag = match[1]

    # Текст без тега
    text = text[len(tag):]

    items = re.findall(r'[.#][\w-]+', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    id_ = ''
    class_ = []

    for x in items:
        prefix, value = x[0], x[1:]

        if prefix.startswith('#'):
            id_ = value
        else:
            class_.append(value)

    return tag, ' '.join(class_), id_
```

Answer (score 0):

Если данные всегда в таком "виде", можно вот так:

```
import ast

tpl = ('p.my-class#my-id', 'hello')

ostr = tpl[0][1:]
ostr = ostr.replace('.', '\'class\':\'')
ostr = ostr.replace('#', '\', \'id\': \'')
ostr = f"{{{ostr}'}}"

odict = ast.literal_eval(ostr)

print(f"<p id=\"{odict['id']}\" class=\"{odict['id']}\">{tpl[1]}</p>")
```

Вывод:

```
<p id="my-id" class="my-id">hello</p>
```